# Subclass multiple UIVIew Types with common methods

Tags: objective-c, swift

In Objective-C/Swift, how to subclass multiple UIViews with common methods?
For example, subclassing UILabel and UITextView where setText method is common. I don't want to duplicate the code for two separate classes inheriting from UILabel and UITextView respectively. I want a single class that uses the setText method independently if "self" is a UILabel or UITextView. Also I would like to be able to set this class in Storyboard for UILabels and UITextViews.

Thanks,

Comment: Just curious, why would want to inherit from 2 `UIView` subclasses ?

Comment: I'm performing some tasks that must work in both UILabel and UITextView objects. Both are using the same methods of my tasks, for example "setText", thus I don't want to duplicate the code and use a single class. Right now, I'm using 2 classes with the exact same code and methods, which one is a UILabel subclass and the other is a UITextView subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least not easily. In Swift, you can declare a protocol that has a `setText()` method, and then subclass `UILabel` and `UITextView` with versions that implement that protocol. But because both of those are `UIView` subclasses, and thus Objective-C compatible, it's probably a better idea to use the Objective-C method `[NSObject respondsToSelector:]` and pass in `@selector(setText:)` to determine whether the objects conform to that method, and if so, call `setText:` on them.

Comment: If I use respondsToSelector I will need to check if it responds on every line I call a UILabel/UITextView method. I would like to make the compiler understand that self is a UILabel or a UITextView, thus would be no need for this check every time.

Answer (score 0):

In objective-c you can define a protocol that declares the common subset of existing methods or properties

```
@protocol TextViewType <NSObject>
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *text;
@end
```

Now you can declare conformance to this protocol for existing classes by using empty categories on those classes

```
@interface UILabel (Text) <TextViewType>
@end

@interface UITextView (Text)<TextViewType>
@end

@interface UITextField (Text)<TextViewType>
@end
```

That's it. Now you can use it like

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet id<TextViewType> label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet id<TextViewType> textView;
```

and

```
[self.label setText:@"Title"];
[self.textView setText:@"Lorem Ipsum"];
```

---

In Swift this can be done similar:

```
import UIKit

protocol TextViewType {
    var text: String? { set get }
}

extension UILabel: TextViewType {}
extension UITextField : TextViewType {}
```

But it wont work for

```
extension UITextView : TextViewType {}
```

This is because of different optionals:

`UILabel` and `UITextField` own this property:

```
var text: String?
```

while `UITextView` owns this:

```
var text: String!
```

Here you can do use protocol inheritance and protocol extensions:

```
protocol TextViewType {
    var theText: String? { set get }
}
```

This defines the interface we want to use later

```
protocol OptionalTextViewType: TextViewType {
    var text: String? { set get }
}
```

This specialisation of `TextViewType` defines the backing variable `var text: String?`

```
protocol ImplicitUnwrappedOptionalTextViewType: TextViewType {
    var text: String! { set get }
}
```

This specialisation of `TextViewType` defines the backing variable `var text: String!`

Now we can add protocol extensions to the specialisations:

```
extension OptionalTextViewType {
    var theText: String? {
        set {
            self.text = newValue
        }
        get {
            return self.text
        }
    }
}

extension ImplicitUnwrappedOptionalTextViewType {
    var theText: String? {
        set {
            self.text = newValue ?? ""
        }
        get {
            return self.text ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

Now we need to define the conformance to the more specific protocols:

```
extension UILabel: OptionalTextViewType { }
extension UITextField: OptionalTextViewType {}
extension UITextView : ImplicitUnwrappedOptionalTextViewType {}
```

and we can use it like:

```
var label: TextViewType = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 20))
label.theText = "Label"

var textView: TextViewType = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 20))
textView.theText = "TextView"

var textField: TextViewType = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 20))
textField.theText = "TextField"
```

as `label`, `textView` and `textField` are typed as `TextViewType`, only `var theText: String?` is exposed.

Comment: I also need to be able to set this class in Storyboard for UILabels and UITextViews. Can I do that with your solution? 
Also, with your approach I will need to duplicate all lines using setText methods for each property (UILabel and UITextView).  I would like "self" to be like a generic, accepting to be a UILabel or a UITextView without use properties.

Comment: *Can I do that with your solution?* yes: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet id<TextViewType> textView;`. Why don't you want to use properties? They are just syntactical sugar around methods?

Comment: But maybe you should go another way: use a UIView subclass that takes an object and that will configure itself differently for different objects. in Swift this could be generic. Recently I created an app that took this a bit further. Instead of a generic view I introduced generic renderers that would have an generic property for the view and a generic periphery for the object thats needs to be displayed. This allows me to write highly reusable code.

Comment: It's almost like you did, but if I use properties I won't be able to set this class for UILabels and UITextViews in Storyboard without connecting outlets. Connecting outlets is a hard work for huge projects like I'm working. I would like to set the class as the custom class which is faster to apply.

Comment: Well, if this is really an issue for your project I'd say you are not using the toolbox right that programming is offering us. It sounds as if you are not reusing code correctly.  How many lines of code do your view controllers have and how many are in your storyboards?

Comment: What you mean by not using the toolbox right?
I just think this is a programming language issue, if it was in Java for example would be solved. I just need a generic self not dependent of if/else conditions.

Comment: :D if you are programming objc or swift as if you would do in java, that you just proved me right.